# Font awesome icons doesn't change by onclick method of blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a simple method `SortClass(column)` that change the css class when the user clicks on the icon, I checked the method and it works fine but blazor doesn't regenerate the SVG after assigning the value of the class.

```
 <th  @onclick="@(() => SortData(col))" scope="col">
      @col.Caption
      <i class="@SortClass(col)"></i>
  </th>
```

SortClass:

```
private string SortClass(ColumnDefinition col)
{
    if (col._SortDirection != SortDirection.NotSet)
    {
        return $"{col._SortDirection.ToString().ToLower()}"; // SortDirection is enum has value {"fas fa-sort-up", "fas fa-sort-down"}
    }
    return "invisible";
    
}
```

Onclick method:

```
 private void SortData(ColumnDefinition sortByCol = null)
        {
            if (sortByCol is null)
            {
                sortByCol = Columns.FirstOrDefault(x => x._SortDirection != SortDirection.NotSet);
                if (sortByCol is null) return;
            }
            if (sortByCol._SortDirection != SortDirection.NotSet)
            {
                switch (sortByCol._SortDirection)
                {
                    case SortDirection.NotSet:
                        sortByCol._SortDirection = SortDirection.Asc;
                        break;
                    case SortDirection.Asc:
                        sortByCol._SortDirection = SortDirection.Desc;
                        break;
                    case SortDirection.Desc:
                        sortByCol._SortDirection = SortDirection.Asc;
                        break;
                    default:
                        sortByCol._SortDirection = SortDirection.Asc;
                        break;
                }

                if (sortByCol._SortDirection == SortDirection.Asc)
                {
                    DataItems.Sort((x, y) => typeof(TItem).GetProperty(sortByCol.DataField).GetValue(x).ToString()
                        .CompareTo(typeof(TItem).GetProperty(sortByCol.DataField).GetValue(y).ToString()));
                }
                else
                {
                    DataItems.Sort((x, y) => typeof(TItem).GetProperty(sortByCol.DataField).GetValue(y).ToString()
                        .CompareTo(typeof(TItem).GetProperty(sortByCol.DataField).GetValue(x).ToString()));
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: -> I'm having the same issue. Did you find a resolution?

Comment: Sorry, I do not remember, it was long ago. Can you try to add `StateHasChanged();` in the last line of `SortClass` to render the page again.

Answer (score 0):

I think your component is not aware of the changes you want to made, since the icon class is not bound to a class property and the changes or not made in a predefined lifecycle method such as `OnInitialized` etc..
Thus either bind the icon class to a property that is changed when you execute your sorting or explicitly communicate your changes to be rendered by using the [`StateHasChanged()`-method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/rendering?view=aspnetcore-5.0#when-to-call-statehaschanged).

Comment: Hi Barabara, Thanks for your answer, ColumnDefinition is a property in my component, so ColumnDefinition  is a class the has the config of my columns and one of the config is css value. About StatehasChanged, I called this method en the end of SortData after addding some delay but SVG is still the same.

Comment: Could you please provide your code (e.g. in [BlazorFiddle](https://blazorfiddle.com/) to be enable to reproduce the scenario?