# Blazor Server: Font Awesome Icon not updating on filter data change

Tags: font-awesome, blazor-server-side, syncfusion, .net-8.0

.Net 8/Blazor Server

I have a blazor server app that uses font awesome.

On my Index razor page, I have a sync fusion blazor SfCard that adds the cards based on a filter data source for menu items. The card has a button at the bottom. If the menu item for the card does not have a navigate url then it will get the children of that card and update the page. If the menu item for the card has a navigate url, it will then navigate to the page.

When the SfCard item does not have a navigate url and has children, all the text updates, but the font icon is not updating in the dom? It keeps the previous icon.

I do call `StateHasChanged()` or `await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged).ConfigureAwait(false);`, but that is not updating the dom with the new icon to add the SVG etc.

Any ideas why?

This is similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66242580/font-awesome-icons-doesnt-change-by-onclick-method-of-blazor)

```
@page "/"

@using AutoMapper
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.Buttons
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.Cards

@inject MenuUtilities menuUtilities
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider;
@inject ILogger<Index> _logger;
@inject IMapper mapper;
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject CardToTreeViewSelectionService DataService

@rendermode InteractiveServer

<PageTitle>Home Page</PageTitle>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (MenuItemInfoModel? item in FilteredMenuData)
        {
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <SfCard @ref="sfCard" CssClass="card mb-3">
                    <CardHeader Title="@item.Name">
                    </CardHeader>
                    <CardContent>
                        <i class="@item.IconTxt fa-2x"></i>
                        @item.DescriptionTxt
                    </CardContent>
                    <CardFooter>
                        <CardFooterContent>
                            <SfButton CssClass="e-btn e-outline e-primary" Content="View" @onclick="(args) => onToggleClick(args, item)">
                            </SfButton>
                        </CardFooterContent>
                    </CardFooter>
                </SfCard>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>



<style>
    .flex-wrap {
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }}
</style>
```

```
    public partial class Index
    {
        SfCard sfCard = new SfCard();
        private IList<MenuItemInfoModel> AllMenuData = new List<MenuItemInfoModel>();
        private IList<MenuItemInfoModel> FilteredMenuData = new List<MenuItemInfoModel>();

        private int? clickedMenuItemId;

        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            await LoadData().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        private async Task onToggleClick(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.MouseEventArgs args, MenuItemInfoModel item)
        {
            clickedMenuItemId = Convert.ToInt32(item.MenuItemId);
            if (item.HasChildren == true)
            {
                await FilterData().ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            else
            {
                DataService.UpdateTreeViewSelection(Convert.ToInt32(clickedMenuItemId.Value));
                NavigationManager.NavigateTo(item.NavigationUrl);
            }
        }

        private async Task LoadData()
        {
            if (menuUtilities is not null)
            {
                var isLoggedIn = await UserUtility.IsUserAuthenicated(AuthenticationStateProvider).ConfigureAwait(false);
                var currentUserId = await UserUtility.GetCurrentUserId(AuthenticationStateProvider).ConfigureAwait(false);
                var menuItems = (await menuUtilities.GetMenuItems(isLoggedIn, currentUserId, "sideBar_Call").ConfigureAwait(false)).Where(w => w.MenuItemId != -1).ToList();

                AllMenuData = mapper.Map<IList<MenuItemInfoModel>>(menuItems);

                await FilterData().ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }

        private async Task FilterData()
        {
            if (clickedMenuItemId.HasValue == false)
            {
                FilteredMenuData = AllMenuData.Where(w => w.MenuItemParentId == null).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                FilteredMenuData = AllMenuData.Where(w => w.MenuItemParentId == clickedMenuItemId.Value.ToString()).ToList();
                DataService.UpdateTreeViewSelection(Convert.ToInt32(clickedMenuItemId.Value));
                StateHasChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```